# Create function which returns the row name and the maximum value

Tags: r, function, dataframe, max

I have two different data frames

```
    df <- data.frame(A=c(3,2,1,4,5),B=c(1,6,3,8,4),C=c(2,1,4,8,9), D=c(4,1,2,4,6),
                     Type=c("M","M","N","J","M"))
    row.names(df)<-c("R1","R2","R3","R4","R5")


       A B C D Type
    R1 3 1 2 4  M
    R2 2 6 1 1  M
    R3 1 3 4 2  N
    R4 4 8 8 4  J
    R5 5 4 9 6  M


    df2 <- data.frame(E=c(2,5,6,1,4),F=c(2,4,2,5,1),G=c(5,6,2,7,3),H=c(8,2,7,4,1),
                      Category=c("P","M","T","N","J"))
    row.names(df2)<-c("R6","R7","R8","R9","R10")


        E F G H Category
    R6  2 2 5 8    P
    R7  5 4 6 2    M
    R8  6 2 2 7    T
    R9  1 5 7 4    N
    R10 4 1 3 1    J
```

and I am trying to create a function which takes in a data frame, column, and category OR type as arguments and returns the highest value on the column which belongs to the category/type and the row name.

Let the function be *lookup*. Here is an example of an outcome I would like to have:

```
lookup(df, "B", "M")

6, R2
```

where 6 is the highest value in the column B of type M.

Here is what I have gotten so far:

```
    lookup<-function(data,col,row) {
      maxrow<-which.max(data[,col])
      print(maxrow)
    }

    lookup(df, "B", "M")

    4
```

However, this function only prints out the row number (not even row name) of highest value on the entire column and I don't know how to make the function to take the types and categories into account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the column of `Type` or `Category` with `grep` and `colnames`. And then you simply need tu subset. In case you want to get also the `colname` remove `unname` from the function.

```
lookup <- function(data,col,row) {
  i <- which(data[,grep("Type|Category", colnames(data))]==row)
  j <- which.max(data[i, col])
  unname(data[i[j], col, drop = FALSE])
}
lookup(df, "B", "M")
#    
#R2 6
```

Answer (score 1):

some small changes to your function. This requires that the `Type` or `Category` etc is always the last column.

```
lookup<-function(data,col,row) {
      maxrow<-which.max(data[,col][data[,ncol(data)]==row])
      a <- data[,col][maxrow]
      b <- row.names(data)[maxrow])
      c(a,b)    
}
```

output:

```
> lookup(df, "B", "M")
[1] "6"  "R2"
```